# MFC can't load error string resources in dbcore.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, cdatabase

I have an old MFC application I've recently updated to include code that uses `CDatabase` to access an old MDB.

This works, but when an internal error occurs, I get an assertion in *dbcore.cpp* that it could not load the error string resource.

After some research, I added the following line to my application's RC file.

```cpp
#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif
#include "afxres.h"
#include "afxdb.rc"  // <<======= I ADDED THIS LINE HERE!!!

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
```

This solved the problem. I now got a meaningful message for internal errors. However, now if I try to save my resource file using the resource editor, I get an error.

[image]

How can I get meaningful internal database messages and *still* be able to save changes to my resource file?

Comment: Did you try adding moving it to after targetver.h instead  so it is in the #ifndef APPSTUDIO_INVOKED block?  Or tried moving it to your .rc2 file? (Generally, MFC projects have a YourProject.rc2 file. (YourProject is just an alias for whatever your project name is.)

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: Moving it to the RC2 file seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Joe Willcoxson's comment, moving the added line to my RC2 file solved the issue. I now have the necessary database resources, and I'm still able to edit and save resources in the resource editor.